# Serving React application with Apache works, but loading JSON from same server fails with 503

Tags: json, reactjs, apache, asynchronous

I'm serving a React application with Apache and serve (as indicated by react-scripts build process), and the application loads fine, but one functionality requires asynchronously loading a static JSON (that's generated during build time) from the root directory of the application, and, for some reason, that fails with a "503 - Service unavailable". That's the only file that has problems loading. All the other files are images, not loaded asynchronously, and they are loaded without problems.

Also, locally it works just fine!

Any idea on what might be the cause of the issue?

Tnx for reading,

Comment: I guess apache config has something to do with the error. Do you have access to the config? Maybe Apache tries to do something for *.json files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by running the nodejs process as a background process. Followed a hint I found here:

https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17021/solved-http-failed-to-make-connection-to-backend-localhost#answer-66876

So, instead of starting my app with

```
serve /path/to/application
```

I started it with

```
nohup serve /path/to/application & disown
```

That did the trick.